# Windows 10 install went to a black screen

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-installation, black-screen-of-death, blank-screen

I had a Windows 8.1 laptop PC and wanted to install Windows 10 on it. I used the tool from Windows to do so, and it was all going fine, left home when it was about 30% complete with the install. When I came home, there was just a black screen. I tried hitting some keys and moving the mouse around and nothing happened on screen nor did the computer make any noise, only the fan whirring quietly. I disconnected it from the charger and looked to see if it responded or something but no. So I held down the power button to do the emergency shutoff. I powered it back up and like I saw one of those command windows pop up for half a second and then a black screen all over again. The switch for the lights on the light up keyboard worked, but still no pointer, just a black screen.  I did the emergency off a third time, and this time after that half second of the command prompt window things started happening.  It says it's trying to restore my previous version of Windows.

I just want my pc to work again, if it could get windows 10 that would be great, but if it can never upgrade well it'll do I guess.

Comment: Is there a question? After the restore your PC will work again.

Comment: Check with the driver version here have a look at this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/after-installing-windows-10-black-screen-with/e0ec440d-c2db-4c9d-8854-999e0b05333b?page=3&auth=1 thread this issue might occur due to driver.